# What are the operator methods for boolean 'and', 'or' in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, operator-keyword

For instance, these are defined in the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) and can be used as such:

```
import operator
print operator.__add__   # alias add -> +
print operator.__sub__   # alias sub -> -
print operator.__and__   # alias and_ -> &
print operator.__or__    # alias or_ -> |
```

Then what is the equivalent of `and` and `or`?

```
print operator."and ?????"  # should be boolean-and
print operator."or ????"    # should be boolean-or
```

Comment: What's the question? `and` and `or` have to be special because they short-circuit.

Comment: If you don't want the function to be equivalent (i.e. short-circuiting) just use a lambda.

Comment: This *is* a real question, even if not really written clearly as such.

Comment: I vote for reopening as it has been rewritten and the question itself is interesting.

Comment: +1 for re-opening; the question is absolutely relevant.

Comment: Still can't understand why it has been closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These do not exist. The best you can do is to replace them with a lambda:

```
band = (lambda x,y: x and y)
bor = (lambda x,y: x or y)
```

The reason is you can not implement the complete behavior of `and` or `or` because they can short circuit.

E.G:

```
if variable or long_fonction_to_execute():
    # do stuff
```

If `variable` is `True`, the `long_fonction_to_execute` will never be called because Python knows than `or` has to return `True` anyway. It's an optimization. It's a very desirable feature most of the time, as it can save a lot of useless processing.

But it means you cannot make it a function:

E.G:

```
if bor(variable, long_fonction_to_execute()):
    # do stuff
```

In that case, `long_fonction_to_execute` is called even before being evaluated.

Luckily, you rarely need something like that given the fact that you an use generators and list comprehensions.

Comment: Those don’t short circuit, of course.

Answer (score 12):

The `and` and `or` operators don't have an equivalent in the operator module, because they can't be implemented as a function.  This is because they are short-circuiting: they may not evaluate their second operand depending on the outcome of the first.

Comment: good rationale for their absence

Answer (score 3):

**Extension of e-satis's answer:**

```
lazyand = (lambda x,y: x() and y())
lazyor = (lambda x,y: x() or y())
```

The difference here is the conditions passed in are *themselves thunks* (functions of the form "() -> value") which are only evaluated as needed. (It could be argued that only `y` needs to be lazily evaluated, but I wrote it as such for consistency).

That is, this preserves the "lazy" aspect of `and` (and `or`) at the expense of more verbose code and more objects/method invocations.

```
andexpr = lazyand(lambda: false, lambda: never_executed())
andexpr() # false
```

I would be hard pressed to actually *recommend using* this approach though - it is important to note that these thunks must be *explicit*, as shown above. This might be one reason it was not included in the `operator` module. Some other languages allow pass-by-name or implicit "lifting".

Happy coding.

Comment: Very nice, +1. But of course implies the arguments are callable so this wouldn't work with a property, a lazy gettext translated string or an ORM queryset. Anyhow, it can be a good alternative to band and bor in some very special cases